# Prepared Statement Inserting Multiple Query But Check Second Table

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Still very new to mysqli and trying to learn. I'm moving into something more complicated.

I've created a test script to insert data into two separate tables, using prepared statements.

What I'd like to figure out is before the information is inserted into the second table, how I could first check that table to make sure the data doesn't already exist.

I have googled and cannot come up with a good way of figuring this out.

The code I'm working with is:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', "xxx");
define('DB_USER', "xxx");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "xxx");
define('DB_TABLE', "xxx");

// The procedural way
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
  $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); //turn on transactions
  $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbl_test01 SET testdata = ?, testisotope = ? WHERE testID = ?");
  $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_test02 (testdata, testID) VALUES (?,?)");
  $stmt1->bind_param("ss", $_POST['testdata'], $_POST['testisotope']);
  $stmt2->bind_param("si", $_POST['testdata'],$_POST['testID']);
  $stmt1->execute();
  $stmt2->execute();
  $stmt1->close();
  $stmt2->close();
  $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE); //turn off transactions + commit queued queries
} catch(Exception $e) {
  $mysqli->rollback(); //remove all queries from queue if error (undo)
  error_log($e);
}
?>
```

I tried doing something like this, but that did not work

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_test02 (testdata, testID) SELECT DISTINCT ?, ? FROM tbl_test02 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_test02 WHERE testID = ? )");
```

Alright, after some hard work, I *believe* I have done this and it makes me quite happy, actually.

My new code is as such and it *appears* to be functioning correctly. Until I put it to the test, that is and migrate it into the real program.

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', "xxxx");
define('DB_USER', "xxxx");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "xxxx");
define('DB_TABLE', "xxxx");

// The procedural way
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$testID = $_POST['testID'];

$stmt_check = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_test02 WHERE testID =?");
$stmt_check->bind_param("i", $testID);
$stmt_check->execute();
$stmt_check->store_result();

if($stmt_check->num_rows > 0){
    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbl_test01 SET testdata = ?, testisotope = ? WHERE testID = ?");
    $stmt1->bind_param("ssi", $_POST['testdata'], $_POST['testisotope'],$_POST['testID']);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->close();

} else {
  $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); //turn on transactions
  $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbl_test01 SET testdata = ?, testisotope = ? WHERE testID = ?");
  $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_test02 (testdata2, testID) VALUES (?,?)");
  $stmt1->bind_param("ssi", $_POST['testdata'], $_POST['testisotope'], $_POST['testID']);
  $stmt2->bind_param("si", $_POST['testdata'],$_POST['testID']);
  $stmt1->execute();
  $stmt2->execute();
  $stmt1->close();
  $stmt2->close();

  $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE); //turn off transactions + commit queued queries
} 

?>
```

Comment: I mean it seems a little too obvious of a solution; but why not just query the table for that data first, and check to see if the query returns a result? If it does; don't execute your inserts.

Comment: that's the point. I don't know how to do that in this instance. I'm still very new to this and am struggling to learn.

Comment: What you wanna do if data already exist in second table while inserting data?

Comment: @DaniëlCronk You're already using some of that code. You would run your `SELECT` query FIRST.  Then you would check the results of that query and, if there are none, run your code to insert the row.

Comment: @PradeepRajput If the record exists, I would want it to not be inserted and just ignored    thank you, Robert. I will continue looking to see if I can make further sense of this.

Comment: Is your table contains primary or unique keys?

Comment: yes in the stmt1 table there is a primary key that is incrementally, auto added (it's called testID). In stmt2, there is a primary key that is incrementally, auto added called testingID. There is also a column where the testID from table 1 would populate.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel if your **testID** is unique column in tbl_test02 then you can use **INSERT IGNORE** query to insert your data.

If same testID is already exists in tbl_test02 it'll ignore insertion of data, otherwise it'll insert new data in tbl_test02.

If not then create unique index for testID column and use the same as it'll reduce your many lines of code and performance time.

Below is the code:

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_test02 (testdata, testID) VALUES (?,?)");
```